# Exciting news on PDII certification, no progamming assignments, cost is $200

Tags: discussion

Effective June 28, the PDII certification will consist of two parts: a proctored multiple-choice exam (the same one that exists today) and four Trailhead Superbadges which replace the Programming Assignment. Similar to the Programming Assignment, superbadges show that you can take what you've learned and apply it to advanced, real-world business requirements. Covering features, concepts, and scenarios that are essential for a Platform Developer to know, including Apex programming, data integration and more, these superbadges will be the final step on the journey to a PDII certification.

Refer [Changes to the Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II Credential](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Changes-to-Platform-Developer-II)

Comment: This will get away from the bottleneck with the programming assignments so it is good news.

Comment: I think it will loose true value of passing the exam. Salesforce is automating effort to verify assignments through trailheads

Comment: And trailheads are known and published. Makes it easy to share code. Now everyone will be asking for and getting code dumps....While the efficiency is nice, the utility is horrible IMHO. It really degrades the credential. Although, I have yet to see having the credential be a deciding factor in employment so I guess it may not matter

Comment: Most places I see advertising want evidence of working in a development role as a SF developer above the certs. I agree with the fact that it could devalue the qualification now due to the leakage of trailhead answers and code dumps.

Comment: I am one of those ones cleared the first round and was waiting for programming assignment, like eric said i kind of feel the real value of this certification is diluted with this automated verification.

Comment: @RedDevil, you can ask salesforce to give you $200 back.

Comment: @SantanuBoral, They gave me a 200$ voucher code which i will use for one of the domain certifications which i am planning to give later

Comment: The trailhead superbadges is coming in late 2017. If I go and take the exam will it be the old way? Even I don't like this new method.

Comment: I'd imagine that SF will find a way around the sharing of code. Perhaps one of several different but similar Trailheads - you wouldn't know which one to copy from.... I also think that's part of the reason why the Trailheads aren't ready yet, because they are sorting this out.

Comment: It kind of makes sense not to have certifications so isolationist as developers do and will use all manner of online resources whilst building applications in the real world. But, at the same time this makes certifications objectively easier so I do get the devaluation concerns too. At the SF World Tour they were **hammering** Trailhead; I'm surprised they've gone this far with it though!

Comment: I recommend that those who are posting read the details in the [blog post](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/06/platform-developer-ii-certification.html). You'll observe there will be 4 Superbadges required. Further, the downside to all this is you can have code that works in your org, yet it won't pass the Trailhead Check. That means, you must write your code as Trailhead wants if you're to pass; not as you might write it for an assignment. In that sense, you're going to be constrained. You'll also need to meet the qualifications needed to take each of the Superbadges.

Comment: Am I the only one who think this change is Salesforce's move to make more guys adopt to trailhead? I mean trailhead are good but just can't replace  the Programming Assignment hard challenge. I have seen couple of seniors failing 1-2 times in programming assignment and finally winning it. This thing wont happen now. Dev 2 (501) was a prestigious certificate now its just a trailhead adoption gimmick. It was one of the hardest out there having very less passing % thus people used to wait quite a lot before attempting it.

Comment: I'll admit, i have never done a super badge but anything that is evaluated by software requires constraints (sans the high end AI) and if those constraints exist then a public super badge will have the exact code needed to pass out there in the wild, possibly even in a unmanaged package for sale by some eager entrepreneur . Game over on the credential. It will become as easy to pass as the maintenance exams (a bit of an over exaggeration I know). Hope I am wrong.....

Comment: With Salesforce DX code sharing of completed trailheads becomes a mere triviality. I love the super badges - they are fun, I cannot say  whether they are 'hard' but there are tricky parts in there for sure. 
I can see the devaluing aspect. To me the scaling aspect is of higher importance though. We need more people into Salesforce to fulfill the demand. Superbadges might not be the same level of qualification as platform II now - maybe even intentionally so: It will enable a lot more people to get a position with that cert.

Comment: More certifications, less overhead, same price, great business! Next up, the TA exam is replaced by Trailhead Superduperbadges -and still costs $6000.